# calculate value for every 12 counts

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

```js
function myFunction() {
  diff = 2;
  var l = 12;

  b = document.getElementById("yee").value;

  var a = Number(document.getElementById("base").value);
  var aa = (a * b) / 100;
  z = aa;
  var r = "";
  k = 0;
  m = 0;
  e = 0;
  z = 0;
  
  const yr_arr = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < diff; i++) {
    if (i) {
      var hk = (aa * document.getElementById("per").value) / 100;
      aa += Number(hk);

    }
    n = m;

    
    for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {

      var d = ((aa * n) * 5) / 12 / 100;
      var f  = d+z;

      r += k + 1 + ") " + aa.toFixed(2) + "---" + f.toFixed(2) + "<br/>";
      k++;
      n++;
      
      yr_arr.push({ x: aa });
    }
    
  
    r += "";
    m++;
    z = z + d;

  }
  
  const yr_result = yr_arr.reduce( ( sum, { x } ) => sum + x , 0);
 document.getElementById("yr_demo1").innerHTML += yr_result.toFixed(2);
    
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += r;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>Base Quantity</span>
  <input type="text" id="base" value="10000" />
</div>
<div>
  <span>Base Percent</span>
  <input type="text" id="yee" value="12" />
</div>
<div>
  <span>Whole Percent</span>
  <input type="text" id="per" value="10" />
</div>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<p id="yr_demo1"></p>
```

Here, I am trying to calculate some percentage and displaying it. Also, I am trying to get the total value of 2nd column. I achieved it using javascript reduce.

For example, in above code you can see 1200 showing for 12 times and 1320 showing for next 12 times. And I can get the total value of 30240 (12*1200+12*1320). But, I also want to print it for every 12 counts. I want to show the value of 14400 after 12 count and 15840 after next 12 count.

**Output, What I am expect**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calculating the sum after generating the array, you could already calculate it during generation in your first for-loop.

Then you can use the [Remainder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators#Remainder_assignment_2) to check if your index i is dividable by 12 and add your line to r.

```
      …
      yr_arr.push({ x: aa });
    }

    sum += aa;

    if (i % 12 === 0) r += aa + "<br/>";
```

No need for your mapping then.

Comment: No. it's just print 1200 after 12 counts. It didn't calculate values.

Comment: I checked my code at codepen, it works there. Did you initialize `sum` like `var sum=0;` at the beginning?